# Single product web shop

Tags: php, open-source, e-commerce, webshop

Maybe seems little bit strange but I need e-commerce/web shop/cart system for just one product.

This features I'm expecting from the system:

- Product Options (color, size, weight)
- Discount
- Tier price
- Pages (WYSIWYG editor), mod_rewrite seo url's
- User login and registration
- User order overview (order id: status)
- Shipping option
- Basic Administration

As far I know: PayPal express checkout is too simple, Magento is overkill.

Is there any Open source, php/mysql based "in the middle" solution that can be very easily customizable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single page shop, any of the above carts are just overkill. I suggest using "ecwid". The free version is quite good and if you ever need to expand you have the option.

Answer (score 0):

OSCommerce is a good open source PHP based solution that is relatively trivial to setup.

http://www.oscommerce.com/

Answer (score 0):

And there is also OpenCart which may be another option.

http://www.opencart.com/